# Switching git branches with Intellij without adding/removing modules

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, intellij-idea

I recently switched from Eclipse to Intellij for Android development.  With Intellij, if I switch to a git branch that requires a different set of IDEA modules, I have to go manually remove the modules that are not used by the current branch in order to get the app to compile.  With Eclipse, this was not an issue.  Is there an easier way to manage switching branches with Intellij?

Comment: What do you call "modules"? Git submodules or IDEA modules?

Comment: I was referring to IDEA modules.